# converting NSArray into NSDictionary in swift

Tags: ios, swift

My JSON string result is like this

```
[ {},{},{}]
```

I tried the following code to convert in to NSDictionary. Producing following error

```
if let data = data {

                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                    print(json)


                }catch {
                    print("Erorr while printing data")
                }
            }
```

> Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x11038e2b8) to 'NSDictionary' (0x11038fa78).
>       2019-08-09 16:14:43.360585+0530 Consultation[2699:64715] Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x11038e2b8) to 'NSDictionary' (0x11038fa78).

Comment: What is data? What is JSON here?

Comment: That JSON is an array. Why are you even trying to convert it into dictionary? Moreover why not use Array and Dictionary when working with swift?

Comment: Don't use `JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers` in Swift.

Answer (score -1):

That *JSON* is an `array` of `dictionaries`. So, typecast the result to type `[[String:Any]]` instead of `Dictionary`.

```
if let data = data {
    do {
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String:Any]] {
            print(json)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

**Note:** When working with *Swift*, use `Array` and `Dictionary` instead of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`. Thats more of an *Objective-C* thing.

Comment: But how can get a particular key in array by not converting to Dictionary. Thought to use valueforkey if I use dictionary.By this way how to achieve it

Comment: You must be needing to retrieve a key from particular dictionary in array right?

Comment: Add the proper JSON that you want to parse. Because `Codable` would be a better parsing option than `JSONSerialization`.